# using loadPostData instead of viewstate isn't updating my ddl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

We can't use viewstate due to some network limitations so we're trying to refactor some of the site.

As a test I created a select

```
<asp:dropdownList ID="testDdl" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server"/>
```

in `page_init` I add options to it

```
testDdl.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("zero", 0))
testDdl.Items.Insert(1, New ListItem("one", 1))
testDdl.Items.Insert(2, New ListItem("two", 2))
testDdl.Items.Insert(3, New ListItem("three", 3))
```

After selecting "2" and submitting the form: after `page_init` I'm expecting `loadPostData` to apply the proper value to the ddl.

In the `submit.click` handler the value doesn't appear to be applied to the dropdown as I expected.

```
temp = Request.Form("ctl00$cntMain$testDdl") '2, this is correct
temp = testDdl.SelectedValue.ToString '0, not the value i selected
temp = testDdl.SelectedIndex.ToString '0, not the value i selected
temp = testDdl.SelectedItem.Text '"Zero" not the value i selected
```

It was my understanding that the loadPostData would apply the proper values to the testDdl control.

I have seen this work correctly binding data on other pages and even during catch up events on dynamic controls. What am I doing wrong above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not all that clear as to your "use case" in which you suggest some reason for viewstate not being allowed.

You should expand on this requirement - and I mean REALLY make an AMAZING explain as to what the reason is for disabling viewstate.

However, it gets somewhat worse, since disabling viewstate will not prevent you from using the control's selected value.

Assuming you turned off viewstate for the web page. (In the page directive).
And assuming you turned off viewstate for the dropdownList control?

Then you still have control state, and the correct selected value of the dropdownList will persist, and will persist despite that on each post-back, you are re-loading the control.

So, this markup:

```
            <asp:dropdownList ID="testDdl" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server" 
                ViewStateMode="Disabled"                    
                />

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"
            />
```

And code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Private Sub WebForm3_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    testDdl.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("zero", 0))
    testDdl.Items.Insert(1, New ListItem("one", 1))
    testDdl.Items.Insert(2, New ListItem("two", 2))
    testDdl.Items.Insert(3, New ListItem("three", 3))

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Debug.Print($"value = {testDdl.SelectedItem.Value}")
    Debug.Print($"Text = {testDdl.SelectedItem.Text}")

End Sub
```

Running the above, we see/find that everything works just fine, and you are 100% free to simply use the control's selected item as we always have, and this is the case despite that viewstate for the page (or control) having been disabled.

So, when we run above, we see this:

[image]

So, really, even with the page viewstate turned off. And with the control's viewstate turned off?

You still are 100% free to use plain Jane regular code as you always done, and use of the control's "Value" property, or use of the control's "Text" property will continue to work as always. And this works without any special efforts on your part.

No need to look at post-data, since the control's state will persist, and does so even when viewstate is turned off.

Comment: Post data was shown for stackoverflow to confirm the data was there and should be applied during loadPostData(). My code seemed identical to yours, until I discovered my `page_init` was handling `me.load` instead of `me.init`. Once corrected, the control worked as expected. viewstate is being disabled because of firewall restrictions and some users will have EXTREMELY slow connections so reducing the page's size is a new requirement we're trying to address until a better solution can be implemented. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Well, often viewstate not the issue. So just some out of the blue "rule" to fix slow bandwidth by some "silly decree" of no viewstate allowed often does not address the real issue. I mean, does your testing EVEN show any benefits in performance? Often simple things like using ajax for some button clicks, or even adding a data pager to a gridivew that had icons in each row (it was running really slow, and a simple introduction of a data pager fixed that page).  So, does your testing show benefits that are worth the trouble here? Good performance comes from good designs - not blaming viewstate

Comment: Firewall restrictions VERY rare will and can and should care or even know about browser viewstate caching of data. However, yes, very low bandwidth can benefit by reducing viewstate size - which any good developer will of course NOT have abused viewstate anyway. In some cases, using session (which is 100% server side) is the most easy solution WHEN data is being shoved into viewstate by the developer for persisting of data. (note how I said the developer!!!, not that viewstate exists and is turned on).

Comment: The firewall cares how large the post data is which is affected by the view state hidden field. Our firewall is pretty restrictive so even eliminating individual fields is only a stop-gap until the dynamic nature of the form (which is user defined) out paces the firewall restriction. Disabling fields was our first attempt at a solution - that worked for about a year until our users found more creative ways to break it - so we decided we could make it work without. As for not abusing view state, we didn’t add anything beyond what the page adds by default.

Comment: Ok, that's fair.  As I stated, in most cases to reduce web page size, and post-back size, things like say using ajax or even partial page updates (update panel) can reduce the size of the browser round trip, and in fact often eliminate the page size if you adopt some web methods. It often depends on what the page needs or is trying to do. (thus the very small drop down example I'm sure is not reflective of your produciton page, since that ddl was small, and removal of viewstate not going to help in that example). So, often viewstate not the issue, but that of too large of a post-back